Can a connected planar graph have 10 vertices and edges? is this possible?
Can a connected planar graph have 10 vertices and edges? is this possible?
Using Euler’s formula, $V − E + F = 2$.
$10 − 10 + F = 2$,
Therefore $F = 2$.
Do I also need to use this formula: $2E$ $\geq$ $3F$? or Do I use $E \leq 3v-6$?
I'm a little lost if this type of graph is possible or not and how to go from here.
Thanks!

If you plug the $10$s you are given into the last two inequalities, they are satisfied.  There is a general class of graphs with the same number of edges and vertices.

Yes.
Draw a cycle graph $C_{10}$ (10 vertices, 10 edges) and you're done.
This is only one solution, there are lots of others.
Another idea would be to create a simple walk over 10 vertices (9 edges) then connect any two vertices.

The cycle graph $C_{10}$ has 10 vertices and 10 edges, so no need to add any extra edges.

Yep, my bad, will edit.

I now understand the 10 graph! Thank you!          I am still a little confused on "a simple walk over 10 vertices (9 edges) then connect any two vertices.". Why is 9 edges allowed in this case?

If you have a straight walk through $n$ vertices, you need $n-1$ edges. You can connect any two non-adjacent (or adjacent I guess, it doesn't really matter) vertices to add the $n^{th}$ edge and remain planar.

If you only want to consider connected graphs, than you can get all possible 10 edges, 10 vertices graphs  by drawing any tree graph on 10 vertices (which as a tree will automatically have 9 edges) and then connect any two of the vertices for a planar graph with 10 edges and 10 vertices.
